# How do I print the Nth character of the Nth word in a line?

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I am working on a homework problem which requests that print the Nth character the Nth word on the same line with no spaces. If the Nth word is too short and does not have Nth character, the program shall print the last character of that word. If the user enters an empty word (simple presses), that words shall be disregarded.

(We haven't learned methods yet so I am not supposed to use them)

See the code below, I am not sure how to get my code to print the last character of that word if it does not have the Nth character.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Words {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int N=5;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a line of words seperated by spaces ");
        String userInput = input.nextLine();
        String[] words = userInput.split(" ");
        String nthWord = words[N];

        for(int i = 0; i < nthWord.length();i++) {
            if(nthWord.length()>=N) {
                char nthChar = nthWord.charAt(N);
                System.out.print("The " + N + "th word in the line entered is " + nthWord + "The " + N + "th charecter in the word is " + nthChar);
            }
            if(nthWord.length()<N) {
                    char nthChar2 = nthWord.charAt(nthWord.length()-1);
                    System.out.print("The " + N + "th word in the line entered is " + nthWord + "The " + N + "th charecter in the word is " + nthChar2);
        }
        input.close();
    }

}
}
```

When I run this I get an error:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:702)
    at Words.main(Words.java:24)
```

I expect to see the Nth word and the Nth character on the same line

Comment: The first problem is that you shouldn't end the `if` lines with a semi-colon. That ends the `if` statement, and means that the lines after are always being run, instead of only being run if the condition is true. Remove those semi-colons, and put `{}` brackets around the code block

Comment: Break it down. First write a method that takes a word, and `n`, and prints the nth character, or last character. Then write a method that takes a line of text, and `n`, and calls your first method after finding the nth word in the sentence (or the last word). Then write a method that takes an array or list of lines, and `n`, and calls your second method after finding the nth line in the set (or the last line). By doing this, you can only ever get stuck on _very specific_ problems, which are much easier to solve. And then at the end, if you absolutely have to, you can "un-method-i-fy" it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User input can also contain less than N words, right? First check should be that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a line of words seperated by spaces ");
    String userInput = input.nextLine();
    String[] words = userInput.split(" ");
    int n = words.length();
    System.out.print("Enter lookup word - N");
    int askedFor = input.nextInt();
    if (askedFor > n) {
        //your logic for this condition
        return;
    }
    String nthWord = words[askedFor-1];
    if (nthWord.length() < askedFor) print(nthWord.charAt(nthWord.length()-1));
    else print(nthWord.charAt(askedFor-1));
    input.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Considering line as your input
String[] words = line.split(" ");

//Check if Nth word exists
if(words.length < N){
 System.out.println("Nth word does not exists");
 return;
}

//Check if Nth character exists in Nth word
if(words[N-1].length() < N){
 System.out.println("Nth character in Nth word does not exists");
 return;
}

// returning Nth character from Nth word
// Here N-1 = N; as programming starts with 0th index
return words[N-1].charAt(N-1);
```

Comment: You could perharps add a quick explanation to what you're doing, especially with the first and last lines which may not be obvious to a beginner in programming

Comment: Even if it was true, the post isnt meant to be read only by the one who posts. Do as you wish anyway, it just seems a little harsh to post code without explaining it.

Comment: @Badda SO is not for teaching you the baby steps in programming. Its whole purpose is to help someone if they pinpoint what they have a try.